# Getting response error in SOAP UI

Tags: java, soap, soapui

I am getting error in response  while sending SOAP request.In response it is showing as below shown.I am using SOAP UI 5.4.0 tool.Can any one suggest me the solution for this.Thank you in advance.

```
 <soapenv:Fault>
     <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
     <faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: Request does not contain required Security header</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">VPS-219-21-7.transfer-solutions.com</ns1:hostname>
     </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

Could anyone help me on this.Thank you in advance.When I am requesting to get ID out of the request,I am getting the above error.Please help me as I am a layman to soap calls.Thank you again.

Comment: As the error message says.. security header is missing in the request. You may please check if you have pased the tag for <security> and possibly that tag will have user name and password.

Comment: Check with the service provider that you are trying to consume thire service and ask them for sample XML request and response. Anyway, I think that you are missing the security tag that should be in header tag of your request